# Install only dblink module from postgresql-contrib package in centOS

Tags: postgresql, centos, dblink, zypper

I would like to install only the dblink module from postgresql-contrib package. I use the command as below

zypper install postgres-contrib

But it installs everything. Is there a way to install a specific module.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reasonable way to install just a part of an RPM package. Is there any specific reason to do so? The contrib package isn't that large and the modules aren't used unless you want to use them.